# Can't install mysql gem on Snow Leopard using Zend Server

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, osx-snow-leopard

There's a lot of information out there regarding installing the ruby/rails mysql gem on Snow Leopard, however, none of it seems to work for me. I'm wondering if it's because I'm using the Zend Server (CE) as my web stack?

Here's what I'm running to install the gem:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86\_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/zend/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

And get this error:

```
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/zend/mysql/bin/mysql_config
checking for mysql_ssl_set()... no
checking for rb_str_set_len()... yes
checking for rb_thread_start_timer()... yes
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh, hmmm, just ran "mysql --version" and got this:
/usr/local/zend/mysql/bin/mysql.client  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.47, for apple-darwin9.8.0 (i386) using readline 5.1

Not 64 bit mode? However, running the previous command without the ENV mode switch, still results in the same error.

Comment: So, I downloaded a new version of mysql and reran the command: sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86\_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/src/mysql-5.1.50-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql_config 
Getting a new error now: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-config=/src/mysql-5.1.50-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql_config
extconf.rb:10: command not found: /src/mysql-5.1.50-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql_config --cflags
*** extconf.rb failed ***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well, I went ahead and compiled a brand new version of mysql for OSX 10.6 (64 bit) and then ran the gem install using the paths to that new install. The gem was then successfully created.

I wouldn't recommend using the self installer as it'd override some settings from the Zend Server installation.

So, even though I have two mysql installs, I'm still only referencing one - I don't even know how to reference the second - but for now, I don't need to.